# Can I make Points-in-polygon output to the attribute table of polygon layer?

Tags: qgis

I have three layers of points, corresponding to buildings of different types, on top of polygons corresponding to output areas.

Running the points-in-polygon function seems to make a new polygon object with the pointcount in its attribute table

I'd like to instead have the pointcounts as new columns in the output area polygon layer, so that I can colour them based on dominant building type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool's output is a replicate of your polygon layer. Instead of writing a new column to your original data, it first makes a copy of it, than adds your point counts column. As such it preserves all fields and data of the original layer.

Therefore you have to options:

- You can just use the new output, since the input is identical to it with the exception of the new column.
- You can use join in your area layer properties and join both original area and tool's output by id, which is a common and unique column in both layers.

If you use join, remember to save the layer in order to preserve the join operation.